# Regular expression not working in drools 5.3.0

Tags: java, mysql, regex, drools

I am trying to use regular expression in drool rule engine to find perticular keywords in sql queries(String). But even simplest regex are not working.

**Regex:-** `(\s|\r)(VALUES)(\|\r)`

**Drool syntax:-** `when Query :Bean(Value matches "(\s|\r)(VALUES)(\|\r)")`

What i am trying to do is, to find **Values** keyword in a query, where  *(**\n** or **\r** or **\s** or '**)**' or '**(**' )* may be present before or after it.

For example `insert into table values (xyz);`

or  `insert into table
        values (xyz);`

or  `insert into table values
       (xyz);`

The code is running without error but it is not finding the keyword.
I am using **drools 5.3.0** and java jdk 1.8.

I tried `(\\s|\\r)(VALUES)(\\|\\r)` also for **\ in java**. Still no luck.

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: `matches` usually requires a full string match. Try `"(?s).*\\bVALUES\\b.*"` if you want to match a string with a whole word `VALUE`.

Comment: So, does it work as expected now?

Comment: You should describe the strings you need to match, don't show a possibly incorrect pattern. And please don't do it in a comment.

Comment: @DebasishPanda Please see the answer I provided below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should bear in mind that `matches` requires a full string match. So, to match a string with a whole word `VALUES` you need to make sure you match the chars before and after the word, and `.*` (with a DOTALL modifier) is the usual choice:

```
"(?s).*\\bVALUES\\b.*"
```

**Details**

- `(?s)` - a DOT-ALL inline modifier to make `.` match any char
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible
- `\\bVALUES\\b` - a whole word `VALUES` (as `\b` are word boundaries)
- `.*` - any 0+ chars, as many as possible.

Tto make sure there are specific chars around `VALUES`, you may use

```
"(\\s|\\))(VALUES)(\\\\|\r)"
```

or the same with character classes:

```
"([\\s)])(VALUES)([\\\\\r])"
```

Remember that a `\` should be escaped to define a literal `\` and to match a backslash, you need to use 4 backslashes. So, `([\\s)])(VALUES)([\\\\\r])` matches a whitespace or `)`, then `VALUES` and `\` or a CR symbol after the word.

Comment: I guess this is what i was looking for. Thank you sir for a quick response.